# GraphQL resolver with DataLoader and nested endpoints

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

Adapting the example of GraphQL best practices created by the Apollo Team (https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-API/tree/master/api), I'm having hard time to come up with a resolver that would result in a list of **Person** using DataLoaders.

Here's an example of the api (data from: https://github.com/steveluscher/zero-to-graphql/tree/master/zero-node)

Given the output of **/people/** endpoint like:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "username": "steveluscher",
      "id": "1",
    },
    {
      "username": "aholovaty",
      "id": "2",
    },
    {
      "username": "swillison",
      "id": "3",
    },
    {
      "username": "gvr",
      "id": "4",
    }
  ]
}
```

And a **person** from the endpoint **/people/1/**

```
{
  "person": {
    "last_name": "Luscher",
    "username": "steveluscher",
    "friends": [
      "/people/2/",
      "/people/3/"
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "email": "steveluscher@fb.com",
    "first_name": "Steven"
}
```

I would like to have a resolver what would give me a list of ***Person*** like:

```
[
  {
    "person": {
      "last_name": "Luscher",
      "username": "steveluscher",
      "friends": [
        "/people/2/",
        "/people/3/"
      ],
      "id": "1",
      "email": "steveluscher@fb.com",
      "first_name": "Steven"
    }
  },
  {
    "person": {
      "last_name": "Holovaty",
      "username": "aholovaty",
      "friends": [
        "/people/1/",
        "/people/4/"
      ],
      "id": "2",
      "email": "a.holovaty@django.com",
      "first_name": "Adrian"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

This is what I got so far:

**server.js**

```
import { ApiConnector } from './api/connector';
import { People } from './api/models';

import schema from './schema';

export function run() {
    const PORT = 3000;

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use('/graphql', graphqlExpress((req) => {
        const query = req.query.query || req.body.query;

        if (query && query.length > 2000) {
            throw new Error('Query too large.');
        }

        const apiConnector = new ApiConnector();

        return {
            schema,
            context: {
                People: new People({ connector: apiConnector }),
            },
        };
    }));

    app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
        endpointURL: '/graphql',
    }));

    const server = createServer(app);

    server.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`API Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });

    return server;
}
```

**models.js**

```
export class People {
    constructor({ connector }) {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    getPeople() {
        return this.connector.get(`/people/`);
    }

    getPerson(id) {
        return this.connector.get(`/people/${id}/`);
    }
}
```

**connector.js**

```
const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080';

export class ApiConnector {

    constructor() {
        this.rp = rp;

        this.loader = new DataLoader(this.fetch.bind(this));
    }

    fetch(urls) {
        const options = {
            json: true,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true,
            headers: {
                'user-agent': 'Request-Promise',
            },
        };
        return Promise.all(urls.map((url) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.rp({
                    uri: url,
                    ...options,
                }).then((response) => {
                    const body = response.body;
                    resolve(body);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    resolve(null);
                });
            });
        }));
    }

    get(path) {
        return this.loader.load(API_ROOT + path);
}
```

And the resolver in the schema would have something like:

```
const rootResolvers = {
    Query: {
        people(root, args, context) {
            return context.People.getPeople();
        },
        person(root, { id }, context) {
            return context.People.getPerson(id)
        }
    },
};
```

Until now I can get the first endpoint /people/ and a person from /people/id/. But how to change it to have a list of person? I'm not quite sure how/where should this code be.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your people resolver to something like the code bellow:

```
const rootResolvers = {
    Query: {
        people(root, args, context) {        
            const list = context.People.getPeople();

            if (list && list.length > 0) {
              return list.map(item => context.People.getPerson(item.id))
            }
        },
        ...
    },
};
```

Ps: You said that you are using dataLoader, so i think your API calls is just being cached, but if it is not the case, you need to implement some cache to avoid calling same endpoints a lot times.